# ModSecurity Access denied with code 403 when using nginx module ngx_http_auth_request_module

Tags: nginx, authorization, mod-security, content-length

I am trying to configure ModSecurity to use it in an NGINX server that has the ngx_http_auth_request_module installed and I am receiving the following error:

```
2021/11/30 01:52:58 [info] 7#0: *1 ModSecurity: Warning. Matched "Operator `Rx' with parameter `^0?$' against variable `REQUEST_HEADERS:Content-Length' (Value: `51' ) [file "/usr/local/coreruleset-3.3.2/rules/REQUEST-920-PROTOCOL-ENFORCEMENT.conf"] [line "161"] [id "920170"] [rev ""] [msg "GET or HEAD Request with Body Content"] [data "51"] [severity "2"] [ver "OWASP_CRS/3.3.2"] [maturity "0"] [accuracy "0"] [tag "application-multi"] [tag "language-multi"] [tag "platform-multi"] [tag "attack-protocol"] [tag "paranoia-level/1"] [tag "OWASP_CRS"] [tag "capec/1000/210/272"] [hostname "172.17.0.6"] [uri "/api/v1/busquedas/criterios"] [unique_id "1638237178"] [ref "o0,3v0,3v96,2"], client: 172.17.0.1, server: servername, request: "POST /api/v1/busquedas/criterios HTTP/1.1", subrequest: "/auth", host: "localhost", referrer: "http://localhost/clientes/busqueda"
2021/11/30 01:52:58 [debug] 7#0: *1 malloc: 000056265DD6F8B0:4096
2021/11/30 01:52:58 [debug] 7#0: *1 malloc: 000056265DD708C0:4096
2021/11/30 01:52:58 [debug] 7#0: *1 free: 000056265DD6F8B0
2021/11/30 01:52:58 [debug] 7#0: *1 free: 000056265DD708C0
2021/11/30 01:52:58 [error] 7#0: *1 [client 172.17.0.1] ModSecurity: Access denied with code 403 (phase 2). Matched "Operator `Ge' with parameter `5' against variable `TX:ANOMALY_SCORE' (Value: `5' ) [file "/usr/local/coreruleset-3.3.2/rules/REQUEST-949-BLOCKING-EVALUATION.conf"] [line "80"] [id "949110"] [rev ""] [msg "Inbound Anomaly Score Exceeded (Total Score: 5)"] [data ""] [severity "2"] [ver "OWASP_CRS/3.3.2"] [maturity "0"] [accuracy "0"] [tag "application-multi"] [tag "language-multi"] [tag "platform-multi"] [tag "attack-generic"] [hostname "172.17.0.6"] [uri "/api/v1/busquedas/criterios"] [unique_id "1638237178"] [ref ""], client: 172.17.0.1, server: servername, request: "POST /api/v1/busquedas/criterios HTTP/1.1", subrequest: "/auth", host: "localhost", referrer: "http://localhost/clientes/busqueda"
2021/11/30 01:52:58 [debug] 7#0: *1 http finalize request: 403, "/auth?" a:1, c:2
2021/11/30 01:52:58 [debug] 7#0: *1 auth request done s:0
2021/11/30 01:52:58 [debug] 7#0: *1 http special response: 403, "/auth?"
20
```

It is supposed that ModSecurity executes a SecRule to validate a POST request that my web application is sending to the server, however as you can see in the previous warning, it is validating a GET request instead.

After some troubleshooting, I discovered that the SecRule is validating that a GET request should not have a Content-Length header with a value different than "" (empty string), which is logical. However, as I am also using ngx_http_auth_request_module module to generate subrequests to the following location in my NGINX configuration file:

```
    location /auth {
      internal;
      proxy_pass_request_body off;
      proxy_set_header Content-Length "";
      proxy_set_header access_token $http_access_token;
      proxy_pass http://authentication-gwy:8080/cmr-experience-serv-gateway-loggin/v1/auth/token-valid;
    }
```

, then ModSecurity is also trying to evaluate the GET subrequest, which maintains the Content-Length with a 51 value, even though I am setting it to "" in the *location* configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Set Content-Length to 0, it will fix the problem.

Comment: the issue still persists. A similar issue has been reported [here](https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity/issues/2341#issuecomment-647009434), but I noticed there is no a straightforward solution yet. Thanks!

Comment: It will be a different problem, you need to check error logs. For your original problem, setting Content-Length to 0 will fix it, see the regexp of the rule you were triggering, ID 920170: !@rx ^0?$ (which means: if Content-Length is not 0). Copy&paste new error logs.